# PHP avoiding using global $database with PDO connection

Tags: php, pdo, global

I have this code below. What i want is to avoid the use of **global $db** since i've heard it's bad practice, and i'm looking for more robust/well implemented functionality.

connection.php

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=blop', 'blop', 'root');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    echo $error;
}
?>
```

Admin.php

```
<?php
class Admin {

    public function fetch_data() {
        global $db;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `people` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
        $result = $db->query($sql);

        return $result;
    }

    public function fetch_row_count() {
        global $db;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `people`";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $num_rows = $result->rowCount();

        return $num_rows;
    }

    public function deleteAll() {
        global $db;

        $deleteAll = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM `people`");
        $deleteAll->execute();
    }

    public function deleteData($id) {
        global $db;

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $deleteData = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM `people` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
        $deleteData->execute();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you heard of *dependency injection*?

Comment: I have, but not quite understood it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency injection is when you pass into the class all the dependencies that the class needs, in this case the PDO. An example how this works for you in your case is below, using constructor injection (we pass in the database into the constructor). When instantiating the object, you need to do it like this `$admin = new Admin($db);` instead of `$admin = new Admin();`

Note also that in the method `deleteData` the line `$id = $_POST['id'];` should be deleted, as it not only uses another dependency( the post request), but it also overwrites the $id passed into the method, making the method signature meaningless.

Hope this helps.

```
class Admin {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function fetch_data() {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `people` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $result;
    }

    public function fetch_row_count() {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `people`";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        $num_rows = $result->rowCount();

        return $num_rows;
    }

    public function deleteAll() {

        $deleteAll = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM `people`");
        $deleteAll->execute();
    }

    public function deleteData($id) {

        $deleteData = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM `people` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
        $deleteData->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but it gave me this error: "Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Admin::__construct() must be an instance of PDO, none given, called in /va..."

Comment: Was $db defined in the code where you instantiated it? Also, I assumed there were no namespaces (in which case it should be `\PDO`)

You may need to get the $db into the code that instantiates the Admin too... again this would be done with dependency injection... 

You  can try to use a `global $db` just before the `new Admin($db)` just to test if the class works, but then you should refactor the code to get rid of that global as well...

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked... Btw how do i call a function in the loggedin.php? i had "$adminLisa = new Admin($db) ... $adminLisa->fetch_data();" but it isn't working... not an error but not displaying any results either

Comment: Change `return $result;` to `return $result->fetchAll();` or `return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` to have them as an associative array.

That's inside the `fetch_data` method.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing *dependency injection*:

```
class Admin {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function fetch_data() {
        ...
        $this->db->query(...);
        ...
    }

    ...

}

$pdo   = new PDO(...);
$admin = new Admin($pdo);
$admin->fetch_data();
```

Pretty simple, really. You simply *explicitly pass* all external dependencies into the class that needs it.

Comment: thanks very much but... "Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Admin::__construct() must be an instance of PDO, none given, called in /va..."

Comment: Because you didn't pass a `PDO` instance to the constructor!?!